# In Graphviz, can I set alternative default values for node properties?

Tags: graphviz, default-value

In Graphviz, nodes have a [variety of properties](http://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html) which you might want to set. However, it's quite tedious to have to set them again and again for every node when you actually just want to set a default for all nodes in the current graph. Is it possible to set graph-level default node properties? Or the properties of an abstract "template node"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done by setting properties on "node", within the curly brances of a graph:

```
graph "mygraph" {
    node [ prop1=value, prop2=anothervalue ];
}
```

apparently you can do the same for edge and graph properties with the `graph` and `edge` identifiers instead of `node`.